# Return single value when checking table rows values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Im trying to return a single value from a table with a lot of rows if a condition is met.
For example, I have a table (ID (pk), CODE (pk), DESCRIPTION) which has a lot of rows. How can I return in a single row if..

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN CODE IN ('1', '2') THEN '100'
    WHEN CODE IN ('2', '3') THEN '200'
    WHEN CODE IN ('5', '7') THEN '300'
END AS ASDASD
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID = 1;
```

The problem is that CODE must check for both and not just one of them. The code as it is will return if for example that ID has got the code '2'.

```
ASDASD
NULL
'200'
```

And I want to return just `'200'` because that ID has got code `'2'` and `'3'`.

Comment: And what if the ID has codes 1, 2, and 3? Do you want to show 100 or 200 or something else entirely?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, there is another column which contains the type of that object table, from the application it is required to add one of each type and thats what is saved in that table.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understad this explanation. Is this an answer to my question? If so, what *is* the answer? Show 100? Show 200? Show two different rows, one with 100, one with 200? Or have I misunderstood? The table's primary key is `(id, code)`, yes? So we can have multiple codes per ID, and we can have codes 1, 2, and 3 for one ID, which would comply with both criteria for showing 100 and 200.

Comment: Please show some table data inyour question to understand the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming codes are not duplicated for a particular `id`:

```
SELECT ID,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN CODE IN ('1', '2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
             THEN '100'
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN CODE IN ('2', '3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
             THEN '200'
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN CODE IN ('5', '7') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
             THEN '300'
     END) AS ASDASD
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID = 1
GROUP BY ID;
```

I added `ID` to the `SELECT`, just because this might be useful for multiple ids.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use condition aggregation, as follows :

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN MAX(DECODE(code, '1', 1)) = 1 AND MAX(DECODE(code, '2', 1)) = 1 
        THEN '100'
    WHEN MAX(DECODE(code, '2', 1)) = 1 AND MAX(DECODE(code, '3', 1)) = 1 
        THEN '200'
    WHEN MAX(DECODE(code, '5', 1)) = 1 AND MAX(DECODE(code, '7', 1)) = 1 
        THEN '300'
END AS asdasd
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID = 1;
```

[`DECODE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions042.htm#SQLRF00631) is a handy Oracle function that compares an expression (`code`) to a series of values and returns results accordingly. Basically, condition `MAX(DECODE(code, '1', 1)) = 1` ensures that at least one row has `code = '1'`.

PS : are you really storing numbers as strings ? If `code` is a number datatype, please remove the single quotes in the above query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the number returned by a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CODE) FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1 AND CODE IN ('1', '2')
```

If this number is `2` then `ID = 1` has both `CODE` values `'1'` and `'2'`.

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CODE) FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1 AND CODE IN ('1', '2')) = 2 THEN '100'  
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CODE) FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1 AND CODE IN ('2', '3')) = 2 THEN '200'
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CODE) FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1 AND CODE IN ('5', '7')) = 2 THEN '300'
  END AS ASDASD
FROM TABLE
```